# Error in login just in server when using WebApi

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, server

I use WebApi for login page
In localhost there aren't any errors 
But when I publish my site to server 
I got this error: 
"The requested resource does not support http method 'GET' "

When I use :
 [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")] ,
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]

The error change to "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

In view:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Api/Account/Login', 
                data: {
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
                    UserName: $("#UserName").val(),
                    Password: $("#Password").val(),
                    RememberMe: $('#RememberMe').is(':checked')
                },
                success: function (result) {

                    window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index1","Home", new { area = "" })');

                },
});
```

In Action:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(UserDto model)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);

        model.Password = HashPassword.EncodePassword(model.Password);
        var user = _unitofwork.Users.GetSpecificUser(model.UserName, model.Password);

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
        LoginLogoutLog(user, LoginOutType.Login);
        return Ok();
    }
```

Of course, the login is done but redirect does not take place

Answer (score 0):

Login Action should always be a Post transaction in the Controller (as a principle, and the Ajax function is a Post transaction). Try removing

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
```

and replacing them with:

```
[HttpPost]
```